# How can i add increament of number in an Id attribut when i have more content with same Id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have content with same id but only the first content excute the function from id, how can i add number to each id Ex id="file0", id="file1" id="file2" etc.

```
<a id="test" class="list">Rice</a>
<a id="test" class="list">Beans</a>
<a id="test" class="list">Suji</a>
```

Here is my javaScript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
var id = '';

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    id += elements[i].class;
}

document.write(id);
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an id? You can just have every item share the same CSS class and just select all of them at once.

Comment: *Where*  do you want this `id` ?

Comment: Because i need it, i want it to look like this '<a id="test1" class="list">Rice</a>
<a id="test2" class="list">Beans</a>
<a id="test3" class="list">Suji</a>'

Comment: I want it to add increment in number according to how many id's i have i the page

Comment: "Because I need it"? Why do you need it? "I want it to look like this." Why do you want it to look like this? What are you going to do with these IDs? In general, it's a bad idea to manage your DOM elements by constructing IDs, and passing those around. Instead, pass around the DOM elements themselves. If you would show us more of your code (specifically, where you are using these IDs), people could give more constructive comments. By the way, it might be a good idea to run a spellchecker on your question title.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. I have removed the id's from the HTML and added them with Javascript:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a class="list">Rice</a>
<a class="list">Beans</a>
<a class="list">Suji</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var className = "list";
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].setAttribute("id", className + i);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good yes that what i was looking for

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to construct IDs. You'll spend the rest of your life constructing IDs and then looking up the IDs and probably also deconstructing them. Instead, manage your application by passing around references to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <a class="list">Rice</a>
    <a class="list">Beans</a>
    <a class="list">Suji</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            element[i].id += elements[i].class + i;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It gives you id like list1,list2 and list3.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Check this one @Drenmi.